# Can anyone help me identify the meaning of this antique Chinese stamp?

Tags: translation

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JkLk.jpg antique Chinese soapstone stamp.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

It said "蓮達" /lian2 da2/ - The Cantonese transliteration of "Linda"

The transliteration of "Linda" in Mandarin is "琳達" /Lín dá/

If it was an antique, it wouldn't be very ancient.